# Spring ThreadPoolTaskExecutor shutdown with Async task

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, concurrency

I'm excuting an `Async` task using [spring task execution framework](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html).
Doing so I annotated my method with the *@Async* annotation and added the following to my `XML` based application context:

```
<!-- async support -->
<task:annotation-driven executor="myAsyncExecutor" />
<task:executor id="myAsyncExecutor" pool-size="5-10" queue-capacity="100" />
```

Wondered in this case - how does the shutdown method of this executor gets invoked? I would like to make sure my app doesn't wait forever for this threadPool.

I could (instead of using the task namespace) define my executor as a bean and then set its destroy-method to "shutdown" but wondered regarding the task namespace definition style.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internally spring uses `org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`for namespace of `task:executor`. 
 If you look at the relevant [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-context/4.0.6.RELEASE/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ExecutorConfigurationSupport.java#ExecutorConfigurationSupport.destroy%28%29) (which is inherited) the shutdown on the executor is invoked at bean destroy; so no need to worry.